# Why "InputStream stream" always returns null? (java)

Tags: java, image, resources

I want to copy an image from my .jar to a folder.
The first thing I do is:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/i.gif");
if (stream == null) {
    System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
}
```

With this, stream is always null. Inside my jar, I have a folder "resources/images" and inside I have an image "i.gif".

Comment: is the image included in jar file?

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html

Comment: What is the location of your `i.gif`? Like in `C:/...../resources/images/i.gif`? You probably have the location wrong.

Comment: @dilix Please don't cite non-normative references where there are normative ones, such as the Javadoc, available.

Comment: Inse the jar, there is a folder called "resources". It's not C:\...

Comment: Inside the JAR where?

Comment: @EJP ok, i only want to say that google can simply point to the samples with description even if you can't understand official description of the method

Comment: @dilix But there's no evidence that the guy with the hobby site understood it any better than you did. The specific site you mention is riddled with errors, as are most of them. It's infinitely better to make the effort to understand the official documentation.

Comment: @EJP ok, you're right, it's my mistake :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

> getResourceAsStream() Returns InputStream object or **null if no resource with this name is found**

It cannot find resource specified.

Comment: Why? The resource is there!

Comment: But not under that name. Obviously.

Answer (score 5):

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), it says : `getResourceAsStream(name)` method returns a InputStream object or null if no resource with this name is found.

So `getResourceAsStream(name)` could not find resource `/resources/images/i.gif` and it returned null.

Comment: I have the resouce in my jar.

Comment: @MinecrafterPGSV Then you're specifying the wrong path or the resource is in the jar in the wrong place.